# Issue related to running of New React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, powershell

I installed Nodejs(v 10.16.0 LTS) and then using Windows Powershell I run following commands

```
     npx create-react-app my-app
     cd my-app
     npm start
```

The actual problem I am facing is that if PowerShell window is opened in the background, then my code works properly. But when I close PowerShell and reload Browser Tab, the error occurs which say

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall.

Kindly help me to figure out this issue. Thanks

Comment: That is the correct behaviour, you could use integrated terminal inside VS Code to run `npm start` instead of separate powershell window. For local development you will need to host your site which `npm start` does for you in `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close PowerShell window you terminate your React app as well, it has to stay opened. Running `npm start` kicks off local server with your app running. If you want to have possibility to have application running with terminal closed you can use libs like https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever, but I do not recommend that- it's easy to forget you have one app instance running already :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command `npm start`, this is the expected behaviour. This command spawns a new `npm` instance in the directory from where you have executed it and directs it to start a server. The catch here is that the server runs as an **attached process** with PowerShell, by default and it is bound to terminate once you close the PowerShell window.

To manually detach a process from the terminal, we use an `&` after the command on a UNIX-based system (Linux, MacOS etc.) something like `npm start &`.In case of PowerShell, you can make use of a built-in function called **Start-Process** like this -

`Start-Process -NoNewWindow npm start`

If you'd like to read more about it, you can refer a blog post here - https://ariefbayu.xyz/run-background-command-in-powershell-8ea86436684e